# SSRS:How to return count of events per day for Month

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table with the following information

```
ID,DateTime,EventType
1,6/5/2013 9:35:00,B
1,6/5/2013 9:35:24,A
2,6/5/2013 9:35:36,B
3,6/5/2013 9:36:11,D
2,6/5/2013 9:39:16,A
3,6/5/2013 9:40:48,B
4,7/5/2013 9:35:19,B
4,7/5/2013 9:35:33,A
5,7/5/2013 9:35:53,B
5,7/5/2013 9:36:06,D
6,7/5/2013 9:39:39,A
7,7/5/2013 9:40:28,B
8,8/5/2013 9:35:02,A
7,8/5/2013 9:35:08,A
8,8/5/2013 9:35:29,B
6,8/5/2013 9:36:39,B
```

I need to count how many times each day an event changed state as long as the time between states was less than 30 seconds over the time period.

Basically I am looking for the following result set

```
6/5/2013   |    1  
7/5/2013   |    2  
8/5/2013   |    1
```

I've tried several different types of queries, but nothing works. I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008.

Comment: How about including some of the queries you have tried in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.DateTime, 103) [Date], count(a.ID) Count from Table a
inner join Table b on a.ID = b.ID
where DATEDIFF(second,a.DateTime,b.DateTime) between 1 and 29 and a.ID = b.ID
and Cast(a.DateTime as Date) = Cast(b.DateTime as date)
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.DateTime, 103)
```

Comment: You have an `and and` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (ID int,[DateTime] datetime ,EventType varchar);
insert  @t values
        (1,'6/5/2013 9:35:00','B'),
        (1,'6/5/2013 9:35:24','A'),
        (2,'6/5/2013 9:35:36','B'),
        (3,'6/5/2013 9:36:11','D'),
        (2,'6/5/2013 9:39:16','A'),
        (3,'6/5/2013 9:40:48','B'),
        (4,'7/5/2013 9:35:19','B'),
        (4,'7/5/2013 9:35:33','A'),
        (5,'7/5/2013 9:35:53','B'),
        (5,'7/5/2013 9:36:06','D'),
        (6,'7/5/2013 9:39:39','A'),
        (7,'7/5/2013 9:40:28','B'),
        (8,'8/5/2013 9:35:02','A'),
        (7,'8/5/2013 9:35:08','A'),
        (8,'8/5/2013 9:35:29','B'),
        (6,'8/5/2013 9:36:39','B');
--select    * from @t order by ID, DateTime;

with cte as (
        select  *, cast([DateTime] as date) the_date, row_number() over (partition by ID order by DateTime) row_num
        from    @t
)
select  c1.the_date, count(1)
from    cte c1
join    cte c2
        on  c2.ID = c1.ID
        and c2.row_num = c1.row_num + 1
where   datediff(S,c1.DateTime, c2.DateTime) < 30
group   by c1.the_date
order   by c1.the_date;
```